# Prove that $\int_0^x \int_0^y \int_0^z f(t) dt dz dy = \frac{1}{2} \int_0^x (x-t)^2 f(t) dt$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Prove that

$$\int_0^x \int_0^y \int_0^z f(t) dt dz dy = \frac{1}{2} \int_0^x (x-t)^2 f(t) dt$$

Came across this problem and I'm not even sure how to start it. I figured that if the end goal is $\frac{1}{2} \int_0^x (x-t)^2 f(t) dt$ then I somehow need to transform the integral into:

$$\int_0^x \int_0^{x-t} \int_0^y f(t) dz dy dt$$

This is just changing the integration order but I'm having a hard time picturing this in my head. Is there any tricks to doing this?

Comment: $f = g \Leftrightarrow f' = g' \land  f(0)=g(0)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, take a look at the innermost double integral
$ \int_0^y \int_0^z f(t) dt dz 
$.
This is over a triangle
with $t$ from $0$ to $z$ and
$z$ from $0$ to $y$.

If we go in the other direction,
$t$ goes from $0$ to $y$
and $z$ goes from $t$ to $y$
($t \le z$ is the same as $z \ge t$).

So
$ \int_0^y \int_0^z f(t) dt dz 
= \int_0^y \int_t^y f(t) dz dt 
= \int_0^y f(t)\int_t^y dz dt 
= \int_0^y f(t)(y-t) dt 
$.

Now apply this again,
and the $(y-t)$
will get integrated to
$\frac{(x-t)^2}{2}$.

If you have $n$ nested integrals,
this will become
$\int_0^x \frac{f(t)(x-t)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} dx$.

Comment: Thank you! This is informative and I like the generality at the end